# Check the limits using Taylor expansion.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

I want to check the below limit using Taylor expansion.

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{n^n-1}}$

For that how many terms do we have to consider at the expansion?

Also do we expand each term separately? I mean do we expand the whole function $\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{n^n-1}$ ? Or do we expand $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sqrt[n]{n^n-1}$ separately?

Comment: Please, one question per post

Comment: I edited my post @enzotib

Comment: Why don't you take $n$ inside the nth root? It will look like $(1-n^{-1})^{n^{-1}} $.

Comment: Ok! And then we write the Taylor expansion of $(1-n^{-1})^{n^{-1}}$ ? @Koro

Comment: Then we can write this in an equivalent form: $exp({\frac{1}{n} \log(1-n^{-n}) }) $. Taylor series for $\log(1-x)$ is known for $-1\le x\lt 1$. For large $n$ clearly $x=n^{-n} \to 0 $. And the rest will follow. This is how I would proceed. Please ignore the typo (it's $n^{-n} $ inside the bracket and not $n^{-1}$)in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{n^n-1}\implies na_n=\sqrt[n]{n^n-1}\implies \log(n a_n)=\frac 1 n\log(n^n-1)$$
$$\log(n^n-1)=\log(n^n)+\log \left(1-n^{-n}\right)=n \log(n)+\log \left(1-n^{-n}\right)$$
$$\log \left(1-n^{-n}\right)\sim -\frac 1{n^n}$$ which is very small.

So, $$\log(na_n) \sim \frac 1 n \times n \log(n)=\log(n)\implies n a_n=n-\frac 1{n^n}$$ which makes $$a_n \sim 1-\frac 1 {n^{n+1}}$$

Using Taylor series, you have
$$\log \left(1-n^{-n}\right)=-n^{-n}-\frac{1}{2}n^{-2 n}-\frac{1}{3} n^{-3 n}+\cdots$$  Computing for small values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n &  1-\frac 1 {n^{n+1}} & a_n \\
 2 & 0.875000000000000 & 0.866025403784439 \\
 3 & 0.987654320987654 & 0.987498689469124 \\
 4 & 0.999023437500000 & 0.999022003720117 \\
 5 & 0.999936000000000 & 0.999935991806427 \\
 6 & 0.999996427754915 & 0.999996427723013 \\
 7 & 0.999999826533474 & 0.999999826533384 \\
 8 & 0.999999992549419 & 0.999999992549419 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Why $$a_n \sim 1-\frac 1 {n^{n+1}}$$ and not $$a_n \sim 1-\frac 1 {n^{n-1}}?$$ How did you derive this Taylor series: $$\log \left(1-n^{-n}\right)=-n^{-n}-\frac{1}{2}n^{-2 n}-\frac{1}{3} n^{-3 n}+\cdots~~?$$ I calculated the respective derivatives of $-n^{-n}$ and got something different which included $\log$s

Comment: @Philipp I wrote $n a_n=n-\frac 1{n^n}$ So ?

Comment: Oh I see it, my bad. Can you elaborate a little bit more on the Taylor series?

Answer (score -1):

We can use that

$$\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{n^n-1}=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{n^n}\sqrt[n]{1-\frac1{n^n}}=\sqrt[n]{1-\frac1{n^n}}=e^{\frac{\log\left(1-\frac1{n^n}\right)}{n}} \to 1$$

indeed by standard limits

$$\frac{\log\left(1-\frac1{n^n}\right)}{n}=\frac{\log\left(1-\frac1{n^n}\right)}{\frac1{n^n}}\frac1{n^{n+1}} \to -1\cdot 0=0$$